# Adding an extension method to the string class - C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, extension-methods, string-formatting

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  The extension method is not recognized.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using StringExtensions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunTests();
        }

        static void RunTests()
        {
            try
            {
                ///SafeFormat
                SafeFormat("Hi There");

                SafeFormat("test {0}", "value");

                SafeFormat("test missing second value {0} - {1}", "test1");

                SafeFormat("{0}");

                //regular format
                RegularFormat("Hi There");

                RegularFormat("test {0}", "value");

                RegularFormat("test missing second value {0} - {1}", "test1");

                RegularFormat("{0}");

                ///Fails to recognize the extension method here
                string.SafeFormat("Hello");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void RegularFormat(string fmt, params object[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(fmt, args));
        }

        private static void SafeFormat(string fmt, params object[] args)
        {
            string errorString = fmt;

            try
            {
                errorString = String.Format(fmt, args);
            }
            catch (System.FormatException) { } //logging string arguments were not correct
            Console.WriteLine(errorString);
        }

    }

}

namespace StringExtensions
{
    public static class StringExtensionsClass
    {
        public static string SafeFormat(this string s, string fmt, params object[] args)
        {
            string formattedString = fmt;

            try
            {
                formattedString = String.Format(fmt, args);
            }
            catch (System.FormatException) { } //logging string arguments were not correct
            return formattedString;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're trying to call it on the *type* string. You need to call it on a string *instance*, e.g.

```
"{0}".SafeFormat("Hello");
```

Admittedly that won't do what you want it to, because the SafeFormat method is actually completely ignoring the first parameter (`s`) anyway. It should look like this:

```
    public static string SafeFormat(this string fmt, params object[] args)
    {
        string formattedString = fmt;

        try
        {
            formattedString = String.Format(fmt, args);
        }
        catch (FormatException) {} //logging string arguments were not correct
        return formattedString;
    }
```

Then you can call:

```
"{0} {1}".SafeFormat("Hi", "there");
```

The point of extension methods is that they look like *instance* methods on the extended type. You can't create extension methods which appear to be *static* methods on the extended type.

Comment: Thank you. It is non-obvious that a static method can't be called from a static context! Admittedly, the docs say, "Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by using instance method syntax." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: @NelsonNyland: A static method absolutely *can* be called from a static context - but not *on the wrong type*. The OP could call `StringExtensionsClass.SafeFormat`, but they're not - they're calling `string.SafeFormat`.

Answer (score 10):

You're defining an *instance* extension method, and then trying to use it as a *static* method. (C# is not capable of defining a static extension method, though F# is for that matter.)

Instead of:

```
result = string.SafeFormat("Hello");
```

you want something like:

```
result = "Hello".SafeFormat();
```

i.e. You're operating on the string instance ("Hello" in this case).

Answer (score 4):

Extension methods appear on instances of a type, not the type itself (e.g. static members).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
"Hello".SafeFormat("{0} {1}", "two", "words")
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Wonder why it wasn't doing that for string.SafeFormat() ?

Comment: It doesn't have a reference to a string.

Comment: @Chris: Because string is the name of the type, not an instance of the type. Note that this example won't actually work, because the SafeFormat method requires two string arguments as well as the parameters.

Comment: I was thinking about the correct way this method needs to be called (on an instance rather than type) and neglected the arguments