# Add new property to string class C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am wondering if it is possible to add a new property as an extension property to the string class. What I'm looking for is something like this

```
string.Empty
```

I would like to make an extension, ex:

```
string.DisplayNone;
```

Can I add extension properties to the string C# class that I can call in a similar manner like when I do string.Empty?

Comment: No, you cannot add a static extension method because extension methods require an instance of an object

Comment: *forget it*. jon says its impossible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676191/adding-an-extension-method-to-the-string-class-c/1676214#1676214 :)

Comment: @Cybernate: It's correct that you can't add a static extension method, but it's not because an extension method requires an instance. You only need a reference of the correct type, but the reference can be null.

Comment: How does "something".DisplayNone make any sense?  The user of your code will forever be mystified why "nothing".DisplayNone returns the exact same thing.  Understand the difference between static and instance properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only build extensions for objects...

something like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = "Hello World";
        x.DisplayNow();
    }
}

public static class StringExtension
{
    public static void DisplayNow(this string source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(source);
    }
}
```

but i've never seen how u can extend a struct or a class which has never been initialized.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you can do this.. however it will be an extension method, not a property.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string DisplayNone(this string instance)
    {
        return "blah";
    }
}
```

Which would need to be used (however hacky) as `"".DisplayNone();` as it will require an instance of a string to be created.

If you wanted to though, another slightly less hacky way would be to create a helper class..

```
public static StringHelper
{
    public static string DisplayNone()
    {
        return "blah";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, calling an extension method doesn't require an instance of the class. You only need a reference of the right type, but the reference can be null.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create your own value type. That mimics the type String with a "DisplayName" method.

However, I can't see why you need "DisplayName" on the type? It makes more sense on the sting instance. I.e. "Hello".DisplayName. See Smokefoot's answer to this question.